# What is the keyboard shortcut to access the Remote and Local tabs?

Tags: workflow, godot-3

What shortcut can I use to activate the Remote and Local Tab so that it can be displayed for me?

I can' t activate these tabs.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't shortcuts to switch between Remote and Local tabs.

About activating them: the Remote tab is only available while the game is running in the debugger. What you have in the Scene dock while the game is not running is the Local tab.

Comment: Thanks for answer

Comment: I clicked right at each node and make root.

Comment: @NinaMonti That would be modifying the scene to make each node the root in turn, I don't know why you would do that or how it is related to the question or answer.